# Get certain row where there is a Value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get a list of some rows in column **"a"** till where the value of a changes from 0 to something.
The main dataframe

```
    a   b     c    d      e
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   5.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   10.0 0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   15.0 0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   20.0 0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
```

The list of dataframe i want

```
    a   b     c    d      e
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   5.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
```

In the next loop the list should contain the first list plus the rows where the values changes

```
   a    b     c    d      e
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   5.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
   10.0 0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
```

I have thousand of rows data I want to use the first list and then train the data and then update the list to the second list and so on.

The code i tired:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(".csv")
df1['a'] = df1['a'].astype(int)
ar = []
i = 0
while True:
    
    if df1.iloc[i].Yield > 0:
        ar.append(df.iloc[:i])
        i = df1.iloc[i].Yield
        i += 1
        if i > len(df):
            break
```

Comment: I'd suggest not saving the rows that way, that will take a lot of unnecessary memory.

Comment: How should i save then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
result = [df.iloc[:i+1, :] for i in df[df.a.ne(0)].index]
```

NOTE:  change the type of `a` if required, and you can use the `generator expression` here if you wanna iterate once.

With `generator expression`:

```
result = (df.iloc[:i+1, :] for i in df[df.a.ne(0)].index)
next(result) # this will yield the next element.
```

or if wanna process each dataframe:

```
for i in df[df.a.ne(0)].index:
    temp_df = df.iloc[:i+1, :].copy(deep=True)
    # do the processing with temp_df
```

Comment: This is what i want but this gives all dataframe  (result) in one big list.  How can I separate into different list or dataframe?

Comment: On what criteria you wanna separate?

Comment: so its gives one big list but the index repeats so when the index repeats thats when i want to separate: like
1
2
3
1
2
3
so i want to separate from index 1 till 3 and create a new list or dataframe

Comment: I'm still not sure what you need. Can you add this to your question and explain?

Comment: Its fine .Its works i just did not see the comma. now i can get each dataframe by getting it like getting a element from a list. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (df is your df1 after csv load):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# group indexes
df['group'] = df['a'].replace(0, np.nan)
df['group'] = pd.Categorical(df['group'].backfill())
df['group'] = df['group'].cat.codes

# create list of indexes you want to slice
l_indexes = list()
for e in df['group'].unique().tolist():
    l_indexes.append(df.index[df['group']<=e])

# execute your code, based on the slices
for indexes in l_indexes:
    print(df.loc[indexes])
```

Comment: Gives me a error 'list' object is not callable